# Correct ARIA attributes for a game

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

How should I use ARIA to mark a webpage if it's mostly a game which is commonly played with a mouse and doesn't make sense to play without a visual representation?

If there's no specific ARIA, let me rephrase: how can I announce that a web-page will unfortunately not be usable for non-sighted users?

Basically, I have a `<noscript>` tag explaining that the game needs JavaScript. How do I explain to screen-reader-only users the analogous statement regarding sight?

---

Context: it's a typical [match-three game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shariki). I *can* (and will) add keyboard access in terms of navigating the board with arrow keys and swapping items with <kbd>Enter</kbd> and choosing direction, but that's still useless for non-sighted users.

If I try reading out the board on every move, I don't think it will be useful to anyone: "first row: blue, red, green, white, blue, green, white, purple; second row: ...".

Comment: Its rare to see accessibility questions, and more rare with the context of a game! Love it! Need more of them!

Answer (score 0):

Where does the initial keyboard focus go when the game is loaded?  You can add an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) to the element that receives focus.  You might have to add a [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) to the element too, depending on what it is (such as a `<span>` or `<div>`), and you might have to add `tabindex="-1"` for it to work on internet explorer.  There are a lot of combinations that it's hard to give specific advice.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I do not have a problem with focus management. I was asking about which _specific_ roles should be used for game elements, if any.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part.  I was asking where the initial focus goes.  Knowing that, you could add some visually hidden text to the element that naturally gets initial focus and it would be read as soon as the game starts.  But I'd need to know what kind of element that is before recommending a role, if one was needed.